# Simulate this slider effect with jquery (instead of mootools) [Horizontal accordion effect]

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I can use javascript and everything else, but before reinventing the wheel, I would like to know if there is already a similar plugin for jquery because I would like to use that framework and not mootools.

I don't have problems with money, expecially for a 5€ template, but really I would like to use jquery because I studied it and not mootools.

The template: http://www.globbersthemes.com/demo/upsilum/

**EDIT 1:** I changed the title for future references for people that know the correct name of this type of effect, thanks to everyone.

Comment: yes, this can be accomplished with jquery - but it's not that difficult to achieve without a plug-in

Comment: +1 for clean question and for 'title' edit.

Comment: @Roxon Thanks! I always think about people that will come after me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i always liked the jquery tools tabs for this - see http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/accordion-horizontal.html

Comment: This answer is the same as the other one (doh!), the example is less good, but I find the link more useful (a library of useful plugins for jquery ui is really good). I don't know which should I set as answer

Comment: Ok I chosen this because I found the library **really** useful, I'm still digging in their website!

Answer (score 1):

Here a plugin that might interest you : http://www.portalzine.de/Horizontal_Accordion_Plugin_2/index.html

Comment: I feel like this plugin is more focused on what I asked (the examples looks similar to what I asked).

Answer (score 1):

Here, I reinvented the wheel. But had looot of fun! :)
Tested in all modern browsers + IE 6-7-8

- Instead of using 'title' images now you can use classic editable text!
- Set desired 'start' tab

---

### **EDIT: added/fixed title support (rotaion for IE 6-7-8)**

### [H - ACCORDION DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/tpJSt/)

[image]

**The simple HTML:**

```
<div id="acc">

        <div class="title"><p class="button">Title 1</p></div>
        <div class="cont">Cont 1</div>   

        <div class="title"><p class="button">Title 2</p></div>
        <div class="cont">Cont 2</div>   

        <!-- more tabs here.... -->
</div>
```

**The CSS style Ex:**

```
.title{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:20px;
    height:200px;
    background:#444;
    color:#ccc;
    padding:15px;
    border-left:3px solid #aaa;
}
.cont{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    background:#999;
    height:200px;
    padding:15px;
}
.slide{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:0px;
}
.active{
    background:#cf5;
    color:#444;
}
.button{
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-top:180px;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:25px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

**And the fun part: jQuery !**

```
//+IE678//// HORIZONTAL ACCORDION // roXon //////
var curr = 3;   // set desired opened tab

var contW = $('.cont').outerWidth(true);
$('.cont').wrap('<div class="slide" />');
$('.slide').eq(curr-1).width(contW).prev('.title').addClass('active');
$('.title').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('.slide').stop().animate({width:0},700);
    $(this).next('.slide').stop().animate({width:contW},700);
});
// TITLE ROTATION IE 6-7-8 FIX //
var titleH = $('.title').height();
var btn = $('.button');
btn.css('-webkit-transform','rotate(-90deg)');
btn.css('-moz-transform','rotate(-90deg)');
btn.css('transform','rotate(-90deg)');

if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version<="8.0"){
    btn.css({
        filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)',
        width: titleH+'px',
        position:'absolute',
        marginTop:'0px'
    });    
}
```

One more thing- you'll just have to wrap the accordion into a positioned 'container' with set `height` and `width` to avoid accordion elements 'dance' on window resize.

Comment: This is really nice!!! I "didn't like" that addictional code for ie, damned browser :\

Comment: @Fire ... neather do I. and you don't have to use that code if you plan to use images. like all other do. (your link). Beneath the 'Demo' i think you didn't see there's the 'accordion basic' link. instead of title1 title2... just put your images.

Comment: @Fire but if you want to be able to use texts - this fix will help. Just test it in IE and set-calibrate (like explained) the titles positions (I had no IE to test). If you have a better SOLUTION..... than I want to be the first to know.

Comment: @Fire ... and yeah, in the IE fix, I think that instead of `left:` `top:` try to use `marginLeft:` and `marginTop:` . try it.

Comment: I'll try, thanks for everything! However I need IE 8 and I have 9... doh

Comment: @Fire ...?...I did not understand you. But now I reedited my H-Accordion (see edited answer) and now it supports ALL browsers. HURA! (Why it should not work in IE9 ? :D )

Comment: No I'm not complaining your code, I was saying that I don't have IE8 anymore and can't test with it so ;)

Comment: @Fire I tested it in ie 6-7-8 , moz, O, safari, chrome. But you can always remove that snippet of code and use images for titles (like all other do.) The rest will work as supposed (the accordion animations)